# Intellij Idea wrapping live template

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea, live-templates

I want to create a live template to wrap a code before the dot.

Example:

1. I enter `userDao.getUser().asst`
2. Press enter
3. Code is wrapped and the result is: `assertThat(userDao.getUser())`

So basically I want to create a live template with functionality similar to `sout`, `try`, `listOf` etc.
Can you suggest how to create it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Postfix Completion](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/auto-completing-code.html#postfix_completion) for that.

[image]

The result will look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you need but as an alternative;

- Settings
- Live templates
- Surround
- Add following line in the `template text`, write `asst`(or `a` for shorter version) in the abbreviation input field.

```
assertThat($SELECTION$)$END$
```

- When you type `userDao.getUser()` and hit <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd> , you will have `Select Template` pop-up. When you then hit <kbd>a</kbd> it will automatically surround it with assertThat.